# Importing a module from outside the current directory using sys.path.insert

Tags: python, python-import

Python: 3.8.6

OS: Windows

IDE: PyCharm

I have 2 files: X.py and Y.py that are in different directories from each other.

X is mapped in source control while Y is not. Y contains the statement `import X`.
This works fine when X and Y are in the same directory. If they are not, then on hovering above the `import X` statement,  PyCharm says 'No module named X'.

Following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder), I added `sys.path.insert(1, 'path/to/folder/containing/X')` above `import X` but still get the error.

How can I ensure that X is visible to Y.py?

Note: The reason I am doing this and not following the typical package structure is because I do not want to move X out of source control or Y into source control.

Comment: Do you get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when you _run_ `python X.py` or do you only get the error in PyCharm when hovering over the `import` ?

Comment: what if you leave out the `X` at the end of the path?

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar I have not included X. The path specified in the question was phrased poorly - it should have been sys.path.insert(1, '<path to folder containing X>)

Comment: @Programmer looks like you are correct - I don't get an error on actually running it. Guess I trusted PyCharm a little too much :)

Comment: @v81 PyCharm must have an option to add additional folders where it should look for modules - if it has, adding the directory containing `X.py` there should fix the error.